# Laravel Check Back to Site

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I want to check redirect to another link from our webpage if user clicking on back from browser I must be alert for user such as 'Backword Forbidden ...'

I'm using this code and that not working for me:

```
$referer = Request::header('referer');
```

or how to check witch URL user backword to our site?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get the Referer URL, you can use either `Request::header('referer')` or native `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]`. But there are (at least) 2 problems with that:

1. It can be spoofed, empty etc.
2. It will only work if the person got to your page through a link. It won't work when pressing the browser's back button or backspace.

Answer (score 2):

The function you're looking for is `Request::server()` which functions just like the `$_SERVER` super global, so to get the page referer you'd do the following.

```
$referer = Request::server('HTTP_REFERER');
```

Answer (score -1):

Using Request::header('refer') will only work for POST requests. 
GET requests are the one your're looking for.

You can use Request::segment(1) or Request::segment(2), depends on the exact URL you're using.

Comment: Headers work for any http request and `Request::segment()` is only for the current URL.

Comment: The refer header is present for every request.